# Compute Probability of Type II Error

Tags: probability

A cola-dispensing machine is set to dispense 9 ounces of cola per cup, with a standard deviation of 0.6 ounce. The manufacturer of the machine would like to set the control limit in such a way that, for samples of 31, 5% of the sample means will be greater than the upper control limit, and 5% of the sample means will be less than the lower control limit.

a.
At what value should the control limit be set? (Round z values to two decimal places. Round your answers to 2 decimal places.)

Value should be in between 8.83 and 9.17

b.
If the population mean shifts to 8.7, what is the probability that the change will be detected? (Round your intermediate calculations to 2 decimal places and final answer to 4 decimal places.)

Probability

c.
If the population mean shifts to 9.4, what is the probability that the change will be detected? (Round your intermediate calculations to 2 decimal places and final answer to 4 decimal places.

Probability

Comment: While people here don't mind helping with homework problems, some original effort is usually expected to show what background you have been given to address this type of problem, what effort have you made to solve it, and where you are having difficulty.

Comment: I know part A. I'm just stumped on what happens when you get to z greater than the number. What do i do? Is there a formula or something?